# How can I find out what courses a Desire2Learn LE user has privileges in, and their roles in these courses?

Tags: desire2learn

My service needs to know the list of courses that a user has privileges for, and their assigned user roles in these courses. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the Valence Learning Framework API, you can find the list of org units into which a user is enrolled. You can do this in two different ways:

- You can make a call as the user (if you have an authenticated user context for that user) to find the [list of their own enrollments](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-myenrollments-). You can filter the list of retrieved org units by org unit type ID (the type ID for course offerings should typically be '3').

  Note that this call will *not* retrieve any role information in the retrieved `MyOrgUnitInfo` records.
- You can make the call as another user to find the list of [enrollments for another user](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-users-%28D2LID-userId%29-orgUnits-) identified by LMS `userId`). The records retrieved with this call (`UserOrgUnit`) do contain role information for the enrollments.

  You can filter the list retrieved by org unit type ID, as with the *myEnrollments* call above; you can also filter the retrieved list by role ID (so that, for example, you only fetch the records where a user is enrolled in course offerings as a student) -- however, to do this, you must know what the LMS role ID is for the enrollment role to filter by, and the values for these vary from organization to organization.

Note that, because the list of enrollment roles can vary from institution to institution, and because some institutions view enrollment roles as sensitive bits of information, it may be difficult to determine what role, exactly, a user has for the enrollment in an org unit. Your calling user context may not have enough privileges to see that information, or you may have difficulty determine what a particular role ID *means* (because the role ID assigned to a "student" user in one organization might be different to that used by another organization).